# Report Builder 3.0 - How can I write SQL that reads all parm names and values?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, report, reportbuilder3.0

**Example:**

Parameter: `parm`

Label: `ParmLabel`

Value: `value`

The user is going to select the value of the parameter they want, then run the report. When the report loads, I want to display on the report a URL string containing all of the parameters & the values they selected. How can I do this?

The tricky parts:

1. There are many parameters, so manually coding for each parameter would take too long. Need a way to loop through.
2. Some parameters might be left blank and some might be NULL
3. All the parameters could have different data types, so the solution would need to be independent of data type.

What I've tried:

This worked, but it is not realistic to do this for every report and every parameter within that report. This method required me to go into the DataSet Properties and pass in the values for multi-valued parameters as a comma separated string of values, which was annoying. I'd like to avoid this as well if possible.

```
select

    (@URL 

        + 

            case 
                when len(@parm) <> 0 --This works. The query skips the parm if no values (or only blank values) are passed.
                then '&parm=' + replace(@parm, ',', '&parm=')
                else '' --Parm has no values
                end 

    ) as URLString
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one hack for you here. This is untested and probably will need polish.

1) First build a dataset to return a dynamic table query and inside the dataset add a query similar to below. This should generate a table with X number of records. The idea is to set X to the number of parameters the user had made use of on your report.

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT=4
;WITH T AS( 
    SELECT N=1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT N + 1 FROM T WHERE N + 1 <= @RowCount 
) 
SELECT RowNumber=N FROM T 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 255);
```

2) Add a tablix or table to your report and set the data source to the data source created above.

3) Add your labels for the parameter details inside the table created in step 2.

4) Add a custom code procedure to return details for each parameter.

```
Public Function GetParameter(ByVal parameters as Parameters, ByVal index as Integer) as Parameter
    Return parameters(index)
End Function
```

5) Add a custom code procedure to return the parameter count.

```
Public Function GetParameterCount(ByVal parameters as Parameters) as Integer
    Return parameters.Count()
End Function
```

6) Fill the row count parameter with the count above

7) Fill the labels using their expressions

```
=Code.GetParameter(Parameters,Fields!RowNumber).Value
=Code.GetParameter(Parameters,Fields!RowNumber).Name
=Code.GetParameter(Parameters,Fields!RowNumber).DisplayLabel
...
```

[MSDN Documentation on accessing Report Parameters in Custom Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/custom-code-and-assembly-references-in-expressions-in-report-designer-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017#Parameters)

Comment: I'm having a hard time clearing the errors with this solution. Could you help me get through them?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I've tried many different variations of your code, but I didn't save what I did for each attempt. I'm going to give this another shot and will list the errors I get here.

Comment: The first error: `The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox14’ refers to the field ‘RowCount’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.` To fix this, I changed it from `Fields!RowCount` to `Fields!RowNumber`

Comment: The next error I get is: `There is an error on line 5 of custom code: [BC30456] 'Count' is not a member of 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Parameters'.`

Comment: Check your parameter names. If RowNumber is used in the query then that should be used to reference the field as well --> Fields!RowNumber.Value. As for Count, I bet you have to call the Count() method not the property as in paramaters.Count(). I have updated the answer.

Comment: I used your exact query in step #1. And using your updated code, I'm still getting the error `BC30456` (error above).

Comment: One strange thing I noticed is that in your code in step #4, you specify that the function `GetParameter` requires 2 arguments but in step #7 you use that function with only 1 argument. Is this intentional?

Comment: No, typo. You have to send in the Parameters and the row number. I will update. As far as the collection sent in there has to be a way to get the Count, perhaps try the Length() or Length as it may be an array.

Comment: Actually, you may not even have to pass in the Parameters. I bet you can access them as  Report.Parameters in your custom function. I also added a link to the official documentation on accessing parameters in code just in case I missed something.

Comment: I tried `parameters.Length`, `parameters.Length()`, `parameters!Length`, and `parameters!Length()` and none of them worked. They all gave either the same error as in `BC30456` or some error that went something like `Class cannot be indexed because it has no default property`.

Comment: I am reading through the documentation you linked and I agree with the thought that getting the count of the parameters collection is the key here.

Comment: ...Doh! I just read this tech article and it appears that the Parameters iterator is readonly, meaning there is no count and no looping. You have to know the names up front.....however. I found an article that goes a step further and will return the names and, it appears, the default values. I think you may have to use the solution in this article to get the dynamic names. This sucks because I have used parameters in code in the past and did not think the iterator would be private :( I hope the article here may give you direction to get the other piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Article --> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/SSRS-Custom-code-to-f73d610d

Comment: This might do the trick, but I don't understand how to add `System.Data` as a reference *given my environment*. I am a standard IT guy at my company with nothing amazing in regards to permissions/server access. What do I need to do in order to add this reference for when the report is run ***on the report server***? We are using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: It is pretty straightforward, unlike this task (10% of the functionality requires 90% of the work). You need to find System.Data and make sure to copy it to the <ReportServerInstall>/bin folder on the target server. In your Report's Report Properties pane, add a reference via the assembly reference panel.